# Replying to a mail with PHP (Laravel+Mailgun)

Tags: php, email, laravel, mailgun

I have an application that uses emails to create records.

The user sends an email to a certain address (ex: create@example.com) and Mailgun gets the mail, parses it and sends a POST request to a certain script in my app (POST: example.com/create).

I want to give information about errors/success replying that mail from PHP, for example, in case of an error the user gets a reply with details.

*Maybe the scope of this question is more basic, like simply add `"RE: "` to the subject and send a new mail. =D*

So, I have:

```
<?php
$mail_data = Input::all(); // All received mail information
$email_text = 'Your attachment is too big, the limit is set at 20MB';

Mail::send('emails.mail-creation.error', compact('email_text'), function($message) use ($mail_data) {
    $message
        ->to($mail_data->email, $mail_data->full_name)
        ->from('create@example.com', 'God')
        ->subject("RE: {$mail_data['subject']}");
});
```

I'm not able to test this code in the production server (long story) so I didn't try it.

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Comment: How to reply to a mail with PHP, received vía Mailgun